# how can i convert bytes into base64 using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to convert bytes into the base64 format using ruby
i tried this program but am not getting the proper output please help me

```
require 'base64'
require 'open-uri'
str = File.new("/path/to/file.mp3")
a = Base64.encode64(str.each_byte{|byte| byte})
puts a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use File.read and not File.new

#### TO ENCODE WITHOUT CONVERTING TO BYTES USE:

```
require 'base64'
str = File.read("/path/to/file.mp3")
a = Base64.encode64(str)
puts a
```

#### EDIT to convert to bytes first before encoding use:

```
require 'base64'
str = File.read("/path/to/file.mp3")
a = Base64.encode64(str.each_byte.to_a.join)
puts a
```

Comment: @user2546156 I just tested with an MP3 file on my computer and it works very fine, you might need to be clear about what you are doing

Comment: my requirement is that first i want to convert mp3 file into bytes then to base 64 format

Comment: my problem is i have to send a mp3 file to an api in the form of exact base64 format but when am sending mp3 file using u r code it is saying invalid prompt...

Comment: @user2546156 use the first example without converting it to bytes as I have shown above, I have played around with something similar before and I did not need to do any form of bytes conversion, just `Base64.decode64` was adequate

Comment: then you need to contact the API provider

Comment: Running the two above examples on an arbitrary binary file yields two different results. These approaches are not equivalent!